# When I try to view an event in the vuetify calendar, it says undefined is not a valid timestamp. It must be a Date, number of seconds since Epoch

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

## What I want to solve

I'm building a service with Nuxt and Rails, but when I try to display events in the Vuetify calendar, I get an error. There seems to be a problem with the display format, but I've taken care of those issues. Specifically, I'm saving them in Rails as YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm. Why doesn't it work? In the worst case scenario, I'm thinking of rebuilding the Rails table and changing it from datetime related to a string column.

## Error

```
Error: undefined is not a valid timestamp. It must be a Date, number of seconds since Epoch, or a string in the format of YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm. Zero-padding is optional and seconds are ignored.
```

## Code

```js
・
・
・
  mounted () {
    this.$axios.$get(url.SCHEDULE_API)
      .then((response) => {
        this.$store.commit('schedule/responseEvent', [{
          id: response.id,
          start: response.start,
          end: response.end,
          color: response.color
        }])
        console.log(response) 
      })
  },
・
・
・
```

console.log(response)

```js
0:
color: "#2196F3"
created_at: "2022-02-18T21:00:11.936+09:00"
end: "2022-02-18T22:00:00.000+09:00"
id: 2
start: "2022-02-18T22:00:00.000+09:00"
updated_at: "2022-02-18T21:00:11.936+09:00"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

store

```js
export const state = () => ({
  events: [],
  selectedEvent: {}
})

export const mutations = {
  responseEvent (state, response) {
    state.events = response
  }
}
```

Rails
controller

```rb
class Api::V1::SchedulesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    schedules = Schedule.all
    render json: schedules, status: :ok
  end
・
・
```

schema

```rb
  create_table "schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "start"
    t.datetime "end"
    t.string "color"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Data stored in Rails

```rb
 #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Schedule id: 2, start: "2022-02-18 13:00:00", end: "2022-02-18 13:00:00", color: "#2196F3", created_at: "2022-02-18 12:00:11", updated_at: "2022-02-18 12:00:11"
```

## What I tried.

・I decided to change the format on the Nuxt side and save it.

① Using new Date
No error, but the value is not correct

```js
  mounted () {
    this.$axios.$get(url.SCHEDULE_API)
      .then((response) => {
        this.$store.commit('schedule/responseEvent', [{
          id: response.id,
          start: new Date(response.start),
          end: new Date(response.end),
          color: response.color
        }])
        console.log(response)
      })
  },
```

conosle.log

```
color: undefined
end: Invalid Date
id: undefined
start: Invalid Date
```

Comment: since, for example, **response.start** already has the value (a string by the look of it, can't see how an API would return a Date object of any kind) of "Invalid Date", `new Date(response.start)` will still be an invalid date - the issue is the response from the API - so some code on the API is wrong

Comment: @Bravo   In Rails, we just use all to send the Json. The content of the data is the content of "Data stored in Rails

Comment: clearly the data is being received with `undefined` and `Invalid Date` values - the evidence is in the output of `console.log(response)` - so, the server is not sending expected values - also JSON can NOT hold `Date` values (like `Invalid Date`) property values in JSON can only be Object, Array, String, Number, true, false or null ... so `color: undefined` is also completely impossible when you are using JSON (unless it's the STRING "undefined" of course) - what you presented in your question - in the LAST console log output at least, suggests a failure in the data being sent by the server

Comment: the first output of `console.log(response)` looks fine, why has it changed in the last `console.log(response)` - which is impossible value for `response` as  for the reasons given above

Comment: @Bravo　Thank you, I changed the column from date to string in rails and it worked. However, I don't know how to convert the timestamp format in Schedule.all, so I'll delete the timestamp and proceed.